# Error when opening up my python file to my browser in my terminal

Tags: python, mysql, terminal

I keep getting this error when trying to open my python in the browser in my terminal.the code reads...

(auth_book_demo-xzfPnOIq) C:\Users\thego\Desktop\CodingDojo\Python\flask_mysql\auth_book_demo>python server.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\thego\Desktop\CodingDojo\Python\flask_mysql\auth_book_demo\server.py", line 1, in 
from flask_app import app
ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from 'flask_app' (unknown location)

Comment: You would need to provide more details, seem like the error is it is trying to import the package `app` from the package `flask_app` but `app` does not exist. What does your project's file hierarchy look like?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.